# Error message "Microsoft Excel cannot access the file c:\temp\"

Tags: excel, syntax-error, excel-2010, vba

The code I'm using works in Excel 2007 but when I switch to 2010 it gives me the error message "Microsoft Excel cannot access the file c:\temp\". The lines where the error is occurring is the following:

```
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Temp\" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("emailnames").Range("team_name") & " CDM Action List.xls", FileFormat:=xlNormal, _
    Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
    CreateBackup:=False
```

Can you tell me why this is happening? I'm guessing it's a change in syntax between 2007 and 2010.

Comment: is the file `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("emailnames").Range("team_name") & " CDM Action List.xls` read only on disk?

Answer (score 0):

I put "New Worksheet" in Range("A1") on my workbook and this worked just fine for me.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Temp\" & Range("A1").Value & ".xls", _
                      FileFormat:=xlNormal, _
                      Password:="", _
                      WriteResPassword:="", _
                      ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
                      CreateBackup:=False
```

I suggest checking to make sure

1. The path used in FileName is what you intend it to be
2. The folder you are trying to access exists
3. The file you're trying to save doesn't already exist
4. If the file already exists it is not in use by another program
5. If the file already exists it is not read only